# How to store and display vector text+graphics images in Android without Flash?

Tags: android, image, vector-graphics

What vector graphic formats can be used to display the in a view in an android application? As I understand, PDF is not an option at the moment, so what other options are there for storage and display of complex text+graphics?

Unfortunately, I cannot use embedded browser with Flash because I need this app to work on Android versions before 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
Look for "ShapeDrawable". You are free to save the data in any format you like

Or alternatively, TinyLine 2D, which "implements a mobile 2D graphics engine for Java platform (J2ME CLDC/MIDP, CDC/PP, J2SE). Developers are easily able to incorporate high quality, scalable and platform-independent graphics into their Java applications."